# Blazor app compilation error when targeting x86 configuration

Tags: sdk, blazor, webassembly

I am trying to compile a Blazor app for x86. In Visual Studio I have AnyCPU and x86. I have both x86 and x64 .NET 5.0 SDKs installed. When I compile for AnyCPU, the app compiles and runs just fine. When I switch to x86, I get the following error:

```
NETSDK1 The Runtime identifier platform 'browser-wasm' and the PlatformTarget 'x86' must be compatible
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Apparently needs some entry in some configuration file?

Comment: did you fix it? I have the same problem.